# Python script to get files from one server into another and store them in separate directories?

Tags: python, ssh, scp

I am working on `server 1`. I need to write a Python script where I need to connect to a `server 2` and get certain files (files whose name begins with the letters 'HM') from a directory and put them into another directory, which needs to be created at the run time (because for each run of the program, a new directory has to be created and the files must be dumped in there), on `server 1`.

I need to do this in Python and I'm relatively new to this language. I have no idea where to start with the code. Is there a solution that doesn't involve 'tarring' the files? I have looked through Paramiko but that just transfers one file at a time to my knowledge. I have even looked at glob but I cannot figure out how to use it.

Comment: is there anything wrong in tarring the files before they can be moved..

Comment: This isn't directly an answer, but it sounds like a job for [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.3/index.html)

Comment: @avasal I just don't want to tar them because I think it would take a lot of time.

Comment: @user1452759: don't optimize prematurely; measure first.

Comment: You tagged your question with `scp`, so why not use that instead?

Comment: @user1452759, I can tell you that unless the files are very large, tarring and untarring using ssh as a pipeline will be much faster than using scp. I _know_ this because I have _tried_ it. What you _think_ means zilch if you can't back it up.

Comment: if the purpose is to back up the files then if you're not limited to python; you could use http://rsnapshot.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to transfer the files you might wanna check out paramiko

```
import os
import paramiko

localpath = '~/pathNameForToday/'
os.system('mkdir ' + localpath)
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient() 
ssh.load_host_keys(os.path.expanduser(os.path.join("~", ".ssh", "known_hosts")))
ssh.connect(server, username=username, password=password)
sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
sftp.get(remotepath, localpath)
sftp.close()
ssh.close()
```

I you wanna use glob you can do this:

```
import os
import re
import glob

filesiwant = re.compile('^HM.+') #if your files follow a more specific pattern and you don't know regular expressions you can give me a sample name and i'll give you the regex4it
path = '/server2/filedir/'
for infile in glob.glob( os.path.join(path, '*') ):
    if filesiwant.match(infile):
         print "current file is: " + infile
```

otherwise an easier alternative is to use os.listdir()

```
import os
for infile in os.listdir('/server2/filedir/'):
    ...`
```

does that answer your question? if not leave comments

Comment: I need to specify the directory on 'server 2' (That I will make each time the program is executed) at run time. And as far as I know paramiko doesn't allow for directory based transfers. There HAS to be a file name. But I onbiously will not know the names of ALL the files starting with 'HM'

Comment: hey, to get a list of the files in the remote directory, you would use the variable called 'sftp' in my first block of code like this: `listOfFiles = sftp.listdir(remotedirectory)` then you would loop through those and match the names up with the pattern, as I've shown in the second block of code. does that work for you?

Comment: I actually used a variation of this code and got what I wanted. I didn't use sftp.listdir(remotedirectory). I used the exec_command to get a list of the files, stored them in a varibale and then got them from the remote server accordingly but I will surely look into sftp.listdir. Thanks for your help! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Python wouldn't be my first choice for this task, but you can use calls to the system and run mkdir and rsync.  In particular you could do

```
import os
os.system("mkdir DIRECTORY")
os.system("rsync -cav user@server2:/path/to/files/HM* DIRECTORY/")
```

Comment: Unclear why this was downvoted, its the same thing as fabric above, I just didn't write Python code directly.

Comment: Maybe because OP specifically asked for a Python solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`fabric`](http://fabfile.org). Create `fabfile.py` on server1:

```
import os
from fabric.api import get, hosts

@hosts('server2')
def download(localdir):
    os.makedirs(localdir)  # create dir or raise an error if it already exists 
    return get('/remote/dir/HM*', localdir)  # download HM files to localdir
```

And run: `fab download:/to/dir` from the same directory in a shell (`fabfile.py` is to `fab` as `Makefile` is to `make`).

Comment: I get the following error: 
Fatal error: Couldn't find any fabfiles!

Comment: Am I making a mistake while executing 'fabfile.py'?

Comment: @user1452759: run `fab` from the directory with `fabfile.py`.

Comment: Alright thank you! I have found an alternative but I will look at this option.

Answer (score 0):

Just use ssh and tar. No need to get Python involved

```
$ ssh server2 tar cf - HM* | tar xf -
```

The remote tar can pipe straight into the local tar

Comment: I need to write a script to do this. And I have picked Python.

Comment: If we're doing this as part of a python script that does other things in python, it's probably best to use a python function.

Comment: @EL_DON, For me, it would depend on the situation. Sometimes it's better to subprocess to builtin tools that to add more dependencies to a simple script.