# How to get files from remote windows server with python?

Tags: python, windows, remote-desktop

I have multiple windows servers in an internal network(meaning, not connected to the internet).
At the moment, I am pulling files from these servers using Windows Remote Desktop, for each server I have an IP address, login & password.

My goal is to use Python to automate this process, I want to be able to run a script that will access these internal servers and get files from them.

Is there any Python module that handles such tasks, or how should I approach this problem?

Comment: [Similar question has been answered. Check if it helps.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831865/python-script-to-get-files-from-one-server-into-another-and-store-them-in-separa)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows' file sharing protocol is called SMB. There are some python libraries for this; the first google result for me was this one: https://pysmb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/